# Missing dSYM files in Crashlytics Today extension (Bitcode disabled)

Tags: crashlytics, today-extension, dsym, fabric.io

The title of this question basically says it all. I enabled Crashlytics in my Today extension, and for some reasons, the dSYMs are not being uploaded, even though I'm not using Bitcode.

I tried uploading them manually (from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data/Timelines-evxmjnxmpmcivkavmpijzakaxkrp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Timelines.app.dSYM), but the web interface doesn't really give me any feedback. It shows this screen:

[image]

No matter how long I wait, once I refresh the page, it goes back to the 'upload dSYMS' screen.

I think the problem might be that the UUIDs of the missing dSYMs don't really match those that I found locally.

Some notes on my setup:

- Xcode 8.2
- Today extension running on iOS 10.2
- Bitcode is **not** enabled.
- Fabric and Crashlytics integration was done using CocoaPods.
- Archive wasn't uploaded to App Store. I'm just testing it locally on my devices. But since the entry for crash reports was created in the web interface, I assume the automatic upload should work anyway.

My question basically is: how exactly can I upload the dSYMs manually? And, second one: how can I make the automatic upload of dSYMs work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is described here completely ==> [fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download).

As it said you can download it from activity tab in itunesconnect and then upload it to crashlytics website.